# Oracle Error: ERROR at line 3: ORA-00904: "ALLERGY"."PATIENTID": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having some difficulties with Oracle and Inner Joins:

I am trying to do the following "List patientID and ages of patients who are allergic to tree nuts.

I have set up the following query:

```
SELECT patientID, age
  2  FROM PATIENT
  3  JOIN Allergy on patient.patientID=allergy.patientID
  4  WHERE Allergy ='Tree Nuts';
JOIN Allergy on patient.patientID=allergy.patientID
                              *
```

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "ALLERGY"."PATIENTID": invalid identifier

THE DDL for patient and allergy are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient
(patientID          NUMBER NOT NULL,
 patientMRN VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
 lastName VARCHAR2(30),
 firstName VARCHAR2(30),
 age NUMBER,
 gender VARCHAR2(10),
 street VARCHAR2(60),
 city VARCHAR2(60),
 state VARCHAR2(30),  
 zip VARCHAR2(15),     
 CONSTRAINT patient_PK PRIMARY KEY (patientID));

CREATE TABLE Allergy
    (allergyID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    allergyName VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR2(30), 
    CONSTRAINT allergy_PK PRIMARY KEY (allergyID));

CREATE TABLE PatientAllergy 
(
    patientID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    allergyID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    notedDate DATE, 
    severity VARCHAR2(30), 
    CONSTRAINT patientallergy_PK PRIMARY KEY (patientID, allergyID), 
    CONSTRAINT patientallergy_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (patientID) 
        REFERENCES Patient(patientID) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    CONSTRAINT patientallergy_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(allergyID) 
        REFERENCES Allergy(allergyID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I am not sure what I am doing to obtain this error.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT patientID, age  
FROM Patient, PatientAllergy  
WHERE patient.patientID=patientallergy.patientID AND Allergy = 'Tree Nuts';
```

I am still getting an error of: ERROR at line 4: ORA-00904: "ALLERGY": invalid identifier

Comment: Well, the table `allergy` does not contain a column named `patientid`

Comment: You've got an error message telling you that ALLERGY.PATIENTID is an invalid identifier.  You've posted description of the ALLERGY table which clearly lacks a column called PATIENTID.  Yet you cannot figure out the cause of the error?

Comment: There is a third table lurking about somewhere, perhaps with a name like `PatientAllergies`.

Comment: I then created a table PatientAllergy with the following code:

Comment: CREATE TABLE PatientAllergy
  (patientID          NUMBER NOT NULL,
  allergyID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  notedDate DATE,
  severity VARCHAR2(30), 
  CONSTRAINT patientallergy_PK PRIMARY KEY (patientID, allergyID),
  CONSTRAINT patientallergy_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (patientID) REFERENCES Patient(patientID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT patientallergy_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(allergyID) REFERENCES Allergy(allergyID) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Comment: I tried the following query:

Comment: SELECT patientID, age
  2  FROM Patient, PatientAllergy
  3  WHERE patient.patientID=patientallergy.patientID
  4  AND Allergy = 'Tree Nuts';
AND Allergy = 'Tree Nuts'
 I am still getting an error of: ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "ALLERGY": invalid identifier

Comment: Use allergy.allergyname = 'Tree Nuts'

Comment: Please don't use comments to add useful information.  Instead you should *edit your question* .

Comment: @user104707 I moved your DDL and query into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a table in your query and not qualifying the column name in your `WHERE` clause correctly.  Table aliases also make your query more readable.  The below query should work for you:

```
SELECT p.patientID, p.age
FROM patient p
JOIN patientallergy pa ON p.patientid = pa.patientid
JOIN allergy a ON a.allergyid = pa.allergyid
WHERE a.allergyname = 'Tree Nuts'
```

Comment: +1 - Good answer to a poorly-framed question

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you're using a column [patientID] that doesn't exist in the table Allergy.

Your table Allergy only have the following columns (if I refer to your script):

- allergyID
- allergyName
- type

Tell me if I'm wrong but it seems to be the reason of your problem.